# Colossians 2, are angels the rudiments (the basic principles)of the world?

Tags: colossians

Colossians 2:18-23; ASV:

> 18. Let no man rob you of your prize by a voluntary humility and **worshipping of the angels**, dwelling in the things which he hath seen, vainly puffed up by his fleshly mind,
>     19. and not holding fast the Head, from whom all the body, being supplied and knit together through the joints and bands, increasing with the increase of God.
>     20. If ye died with Christ **from the rudiments of the world**, why, as though living in the world, do ye subject yourselves to ordinances,
>     21. Handle not, nor taste, nor touch
>     22. (all which things are to perish with the using), after the precepts and doctrines of men?
>     23. Which things have indeed a show of wisdom in will-worship, and humility, and severity to the body; {cf15i but are} not of any value against the indulgence of the flesh.

The question is so simple;

Are the angels, according to Colossians, the principles of the world?, The rudiments of the world?

Those who have the shape of godliness but lack honest truthfulness.

Comment: No - the two are unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

Col 2:18 says this [NASB]:

> Take care that no one keeps defrauding you of your prize by delighting
> in humility and the worship of the angels, taking his stand on visions
> he has seen, inflated without cause by his fleshly mind

This is discussing false religious rites based on false divine revelation of people and false spirits (1 John 4:1-3).

by contrast, Col 1:20-22 says this:

> If you have died with Christ to the elementary principles of the
> world, why, as if you were living in the world, do you submit yourself
> to decrees, such as, “Do not handle, do not taste, do not touch!”
> (which all refer to things destined to perish with use)—in accordance
> with the commandments and teachings of man?

This verse explains what it means - false religion based on useless and meaningless rites and ceremonies.

Thus, two different false religions are in view - one based on false view of the spiritual  world and the other based on a false view of religions rites.

Comment: Look Colossians 2:8 (Philosophy after the tradition of the men, after the rudiments of the world), then Look the last verse in the chapter, Colossians 2:23 (have the appearance of wisdom), i.e: false wisdom.

Comment: Look Colossians 2:8 (Philosophy after the tradition of the men, after the rudiments of the world), then Look the last verse in the chapter, Colossians 2:23 (have the appearance of wisdom), i.e: false wisdom. The matter is that there are two types of angels: real angels, unreal (false) angels. real angels=holy angels=angels of Jesus and the Father. Unreal angels=unholy angels=angels of Satan=principles of the world.

Comment: @salah - I understand this but the connection you make between angels and rudiments is absent in Scripture

Comment: the scripture leaves an area for exegesis. I mean: angels=Satan angels. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Look Zephaniah 1:3, Matthew 13:41. From Zephaniah and Matthew there are two types of Satan's Sons: 1- stumbling makers=unholy angels=Satan angels=who seem holy but they actually have demonic nature. 2- iniquity makers like adulterers, fornicators...etc. Both 1 and 2 are Sons of Satan.